# How to make full screen drawer menu from bottom in HTML?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I want to make a full screen drawer menu and that can open it from bottom, however I can not make open button on page bottom.

Is this a easy way to make sure button on page bottom in any resolution?

Here's my code

codepen.io/WildDagger/pen/QWMXZyz

(I don't know why stackoverflow editor always make annoying error so I just can paste it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place the nav to below the screen. To do that you need `bottom: -100%;`. That way the element will be completely invisible & this will work on all resolution. Check the code:

```css
.menu-container {
    bottom: -100%;  /* Currently -375px */
    ...
}
```

```js
menuBtnClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    menuContainer.style.bottom = "-100%" /* Currently -375px */
})
```

Comment: It works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in CSS and JS

use `-100%` instead of `-375px`

JS change

`menuContainer.style.bottom = "-100%"`

CSS Change in this class (`.menu-container`)

```
bottom: -100%;
```